# AJAX Request from JQuery Code within PHP Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, syntax

I'm a long-time lurker, first-time poster on Stack Overflow (which has saved me in quite a few programming projects before).  I have a unique problem that I haven't been able to find by searching the site, so I'll describe it here.

I am creating an online order form where users can select a food category.  That category is sent to another page of code that runs a query on the database and returns all items within that category to a drop-down box named ItemXSelect (where X is the item number).  I have not had trouble with this.  However, I am having trouble using the value that the user chooses for ItemXSelect in another AJAX Query. Specifically, the AJAX request does not send at all (according to Firebug).  I'm hoping it's something simple like a syntax error, but I've been at it for days.

The code below is Jquery/AJAX written inside of a PHP Echo statement and has certain characters escaped.  $itemNum determines the value of the X in ItemXSelect.

```
\$(\"#Item" . $itemNum . "Select option:selected\").change(function() {
var sel = \$(\"#Item" . $itemNum . "Select option:selected\").text());
    \$.ajax({
        type: \"POST\",
        url: \"sizearray.php\",
        data: { category: \"Cold_Sandwiches\" , selection: sel },
        dataType: \"text\"
    }).done(function(result) {
        \$(\"#Item" . $itemNum . "Size\").html(result);
    }); 
    \$(\"#Item" . $itemNum . "Size\").show();
});
```

This has been troubling me for days. My thanks go to anyone who can help me find what's wrong here (or even at least try to).

=====================================================================================

EDIT 1

Thanks to your help, I've cleaned up the code by wrapping all the JQuery in a PHP EOD statement instead. That way, I don't have to escape the whole thing.  Below is the updated code. The suggestions below have not worked so far to answer the main question, but at least the syntax is much neater.

```
jQuery("#Item{$itemNum}Select option:selected").change(function() {
    var sel = jQuery("#Item{$itemNum}Select option:selected").text());
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sizearray.php",
            data: { category: "Cold_Sandwiches" , selection: sel },
            dataType: "text"
        }).done(function(result) {
            jQuery("#Item{$itemNum}Size").html(result);
        }); 
        jQuery("#Item{$itemNum}Size").show();
    });
```

Comment: Why are you escaping so many things??

Comment: You should probably try a [PHP multiline string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to handle all that.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in the browser on the line that fetches the select value?  Is the change event firing?

Comment: Ixe, I actually had completely forgotten about the multiline string, and I'm glad you brought it up. I'll be replacing my messy code full of escapes with EOD-ready stuff. The reason I avoided it in the first place is because I didn't know you could call PHP variables within it. The more you know, I suppose.

Comment: Single quotes would have also avoided the escaping (and you don't need double quotes since you were just appending variables anyway)

Comment: @Matt Thankfully, I figured out about <<<EOD and I've edited the whole page to where things don't have to be painfully escaped like that. It's a lot more editable now.

Answer (score 0):

All these lines look funny.  I don't know PHP but it looks to me like you have mismatched quotes.

```
\$(\"#Item" . $itemNum . "Select option:selected\").change(function() {

\$(\"#Item" . $itemNum . "Size\").html(result);

\$(\"#Item" . $itemNum . "Size\").show();
```

Comment: The reason it looks so odd is because when you write a PHP echo statement it looks like this:

echo "Some words and stuff" 

and to have quotes within that statement you'd need to do this

echo "Some \"words\" and stuff"

I'll leave it to your imagination how much escaping quotes can gum up syntax when you use JQuery inside of a PHP echo statement. It gets nasty.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just do a live bind with jQuery on the client side.

EDIT

**In your JavaScript**

```
    $('select').change(function(){
       alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<select>
   <option value="apple">Apple</option>
   <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

So for each select you add (dynamically via AJAX) will automatically be bound to that change event.

Or you can go with a more complex but less error prone approach where you only request the data from the server in JSON and populate the controls with the data.

Comment: I tried your suggestion `jQuery("#Item{$itemNum}Select").live('change',function() {` but it didn't fix my problem. Could it be that variable `sel` is not correct?

Comment: $itemNum has to be a fixed or static number or all your select controls must have one common attribute with which you can use as a selector on the client side. Check my post again I edited it